# What heuristic should I use for A* pathfinding?

Tags: java

So, I've successfully implemented A* pathfinding (java) (http://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/) in my game, but that pathfinding doesn't work as I wanted it to work. I don't know where should I look to change this behavior.

[image: Pathfinding]

S - Start
E - End

I want it to work like on the left side. Now it works like on the right side.

I am using a Manhattan heuristic.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to prefer moving vertically before moving horizontally?

Comment: Yea, something like that.

Comment: You should make the distance of any vertical neighbour less than the horizontal neighbours